# Adding model object to list fails

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a model class like this

```
  namespace ConnectBLL.DTO.Response
{
    public class CategorySettings
    {
        public bool NeedsLoginToViewLongText { get; set; }
        public bool NeedsLoginToViewAnyDetails { get; set; }
        public bool ShowAttachment { get; set; }
        public string CategoryPageID { get; set; }
        public string TpUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class CategorySettingsListResponse
    {
        public List<CategorySettings> CategorySettingsList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I am trying to add data to it like this

```
    private readonly CategorySettings cs = new CategorySettings();
 CategorySettingsListResponse csr=new CategorySettingsListResponse();
 public string GetAllCategorySettings()
    {


            cs.NeedsLoginToViewLongText = true;
            cs.NeedsLoginToViewAnyDetails = false;
            cs.ShowAttachment = true;
            cs.CategoryPageID = "1";
            cs.TpUrl = "url";
            csr.CategorySettingsList.Add(cs);

    }
```

But this fails and gives an error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can any one point out what is I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `cs` defined ?

Comment: @Ofiris I missed it in the question. added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere, you need to initialize `CategorySettingsList`.

```
public class CategorySettingsListResponse
{
    CategorySettingsListResponse() {
        CategorySettingsList = new List<CategorySettings>();
    }

    public List<CategorySettings> CategorySettingsList { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are tying to use an instance of List before initializing. Before

```
csr.CategorySettingsList.Add(cs);
```

Insert:

```
if (csr.CategorySettingsList == null) {
    csr.CategorySettingsList = new List<CategorySettings>();
}
```

Comment: or just put it in the `CategorySettingsListResponse` constructor

Answer (score 1):

You are using uncreated objects `cs` and `CategorySettingsList`, you should create them before use:

```
public string GetAllCategorySettings()
{
    csr.CategorySettingsList = new ListCategorySettings<>();
    var cs = new CategorySettings
        {
           NeedsLoginToViewLongText = true,
           ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What is cs? Something missing?

You forgot to do this:

```
 var cs = new CategorySettings();
```

Also

You need to instantiate the CategorySettingsList in constructor for CategorySettingsListResponse.